# How can I parse a JavaScript file to an object with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to parse a JavaScript file that exists on the Web with Node.

The file looks as follows:

```
var obj = {"data": [{"property1":40}]}
```

Is there any way I can download the file as a string, and parse it so it to an object? i.e. so that after I have parsed the file I can do:

```
var data = obj.data;
```

Comment: Sure, you can use a http module to download and parse the string with `eval()`. But remember, eval is evil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for it, but be careful - you can also execute unwanted code

```js
const fileContent = 'var obj = {"data": [{"property1":40}]}';
eval(fileContent);
var data = obj.data;
console.log(data);
```